# Cannot change PHP default version in Symfony 4.12

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, laragon

I would like to create a Symfony project. I have the same issue as many people concerning php version: Symfony uses the wrong one.

```
λ php -version
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:24:02) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

λ symfony -V
Symfony CLI version v4.12.4 (Tue Jan 14 13:09:08 UTC 2020)

λ symfony check:requirements

Symfony Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
C:\xampp\php\php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:

..............WWW......W..


 [OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects
```

I have Xampp installed but I use Laragon with 7.4.1 on Windows 10 and wish to use that one, but Symfony tells me this:

```
λ symfony local:php:list
┌─────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │                  Directory                  │ PHP CLI │ PHP FPM │   PHP CGI   │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.3.10  │ C:\xampp\php                                │ php.exe │         │ php-cgi.exe │ PHP CGI │ *       │
│ 7.4.1   │ C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.1-Win32-vc15-x64 │ php.exe │         │ php-cgi.exe │ PHP CGI │         │
└─────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

The current PHP version is selected from default version in $PATH
```

Even though there is no trace of Xampp or php 7.3.1 in my $PATH.

```
λ echo %path:;=&echo.%
C:\Program Files\cmder_mini\bin
C:\Program Files\cmder_mini\vendor\bin
C:\Program Files\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts
C:\Program Files\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5
C:\Program Files\cmder_mini\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.1-Win32-vc15-x64\php.exe
C:\Program Files\Symfony
C:\laragon\bin
C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.35-win64-VC15\bin
C:\laragon\bin\composer
C:\laragon\bin\laragon\utils
C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-5.7.24-winx64\bin
C:\laragon\bin\nginx\nginx-1.16.0
C:\laragon\bin\ngrok
C:\laragon\bin\notepad++
C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.1-Win32-vc15-x64
C:\laragon\bin\putty
C:\laragon\bin\redis\redis-x64-3.2.100
C:\laragon\bin\telnet
C:\laragon\usr\bin
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\.bin
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Ruby26-x64\bin
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm 2019.2.3\bin
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\DataGrip 2019.2.5\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
C:\Program Files\cmder_mini
```

(I checked user & system $PATH)

I tried to force Symfony into using 7.4.1 by running in a project directory:

`λ echo "7.4.1" > .phpversion`

When I run

```
λ symfony local:php:refresh

λ symfony local:php:list
```

I get:

```
λ WARNING the current dir requires PHP "7.4.1" (.php-version from current dir: C:\laragon\www\CMS_test\.php-version), but this version is not available
```

---

I also tried renaming the Xampp directory name, and as a matter of fact, that "works".

```
C:\
λ symfony check:requirements
php does not seem to be available under C:\xampp\php


C:\
λ symfony local:php:list
┌─────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ Version │                  Directory                  │ PHP CLI │ PHP FPM │   PHP CGI   │ Server  │ System? │
├─────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 7.4.1   │ C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.4.1-Win32-vc15-x64 │ php.exe │         │ php-cgi.exe │ PHP CGI │ *       │
└─────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘

The current PHP version is selected from default version in $PATH
```

But that solution isn't really satisfying to me.

I've search StackOverflow for several hours, tried to re-install Symfony, restart the computer, ask friends etc no one seem to have another solution.

So, why does Symfony search for php in a Xampp directory ? Is it possible to choose another default one like Laragon's ? Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Xampp and check if that works?

Comment: @ReynierPM The problem is I don't want to... I am in apprenticeship, and sometimes need xampp for team projects.

Comment: The idea is to see if for some reason Xampp is adding things in the ENV variables or somewhere else like Windows Registry, you can uninstall it, give it a try see if it works and install it back. You will be narrowing the issue

Comment: EDIT: I can change xampp's php version, but again, I sometimes need it with a specific version. I'll try to uninstall, I come back to you soon

Comment: You're not reading my suggestion: I've said uninstall, try, see if works, and install it back. I don't see any issues with that. I am not telling you get rid of Xampp

Comment: Yes I got that I just answered a little bit late sorry !
I tried uninstalling, and  symfony local:php:list didn't mention xampp.
When I installed it back, xampp reappeared on local:php:list. I checked the ENV variables but no trace of Xampp so I guess you're right, Xampp seems to add things elsewhere...

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem on my Windows environment. For some reason, symfony is not reading .php-version correctly when I create it using `echo "7.2" > .php-version`.

The problem was gone once I deleted and created a new text file from my IDE. Probably creating it using vscode `code .php-version` or using the File Explorer would work too (I didn't try it, yet).

Edit: I just tried creating the file with VS Code and Notepad - Both worked. But I still don't know why it doesn't work when creating with `echo`...

Edit2: I think I got it. Looks like PowerShell's `echo "" > file` will create the file with UTF-16 encoding. After converting the file to UTF-8 it worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried echo 7.3.13 > .php-version and checked the charset with notepad++ but it was UTF_8...
I also tried to create from windows explorer and PhpStorm but same result either way:
WARNING the current dir requires PHP 7.3.13 (.php-version from current dir: C:\laragon\www\sfCMS\.php-version), but this version is not available

Comment: Do `symfony local:php:list` shows the 7.3.13 version? In your question it only shows 7.3.10.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your .php-version file and create in manually from your ide! With the from encoding (using echo from terminal) the error message was

```
the current dir requires PHP ��7.4.10
```

you can see the encoding is wrong by the question marks.
Creating the file from the ide fixed my problem!